# Como elimino columnas de un CSV con sed?

Tags: linux, regex, ubuntu, sed, procesamiento-de-texto

Tengo el siguiente csv: (pongo las 5 primeras filas, la primera son los titulos)

```
itle,site,country,year_release,box_office,director,number_of_subjects,subject,type_of_subject,race_known,subject_race,person_of_color,subject_sex,lead_actor_actress
10 Rillington Place,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066730/,UK,1971,-,Richard Fleischer,1,John Christie,Criminal,Unknown,,0,Male,Richard Attenborough
12 Years a Slave,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2024544/,US/UK,2013,$56.7M,Steve McQueen,1, Solomon Northup,Other,Known,African American,1,Male,Chiwetel Ejiofor
127 Hours,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1542344/,US/UK,2010,$18.3M,Danny Boyle,1,Aron Ralston,Athlete,Unknown,,0,Male,James Franco
1987,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2833074/,Canada,2014,-,Ricardo Trogi,1,Ricardo Trogi,Other,Known,White,0,Male,Jean-Carl Boucher
20 Dates,http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0138987/,US,1998,$537K,Myles Berkowitz,1,Myles Berkowitz,Other,Unknown,,0,Male,Myles Berkowitz
```

Necesito eliminar las columnas "race_known", "subject_race", "person_of_color".

He probado con esto:

```
s/,[^,]*//9
s/,[^,]*//10
s/,[^,]*//11
```

pero no me funciona, no me acaba de eliminar bien las columnas. Algún consejo?

Comment: Échale un ojo a esto (en ingles): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34646/is-there-a-command-line-spell-to-drop-a-column-in-a-csv-file

Answer (score 1):

Si insistimos en usar `sed` con tu archivo `in.csv`, lo siguiente podría funcionar:

```bash
sed -E 's/^(([^,]*,){9})(([^,]*,){3})(.*)$/\1\5/' in.csv
```

La opción `-E` nos permite usar las expresiones regulares extendidas [ERE](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html). El comando descompone cada línea del archivo `in.csv` en tres partes (agrupadas por los 3 pares de paréntesis exteriores `s/^(grupo 1)(grupo 2)(grupo 3)$/\1\5/`): el primer par de paréntesis exteriores captura las primeras 9 columnas; el segundo par captura las 3 columnas siguientes (columnas 10, 11 y 12); y el último par captura el resto de la línea (columnas 13 en adelante).

Si contamos todos los pares de paréntesis (exteriores e interiores), el tercer par de paréntesis **exteriores** corresponde al **quinto** par de paréntesis, esto explica el porqué usamos las referencias `\1` y `\5` en el comando de sustitución.

Una solución más simple es usar `cut` como lo indica la respuesta en inglés que menciona @eftshift0.

```bash
cut -d, -f 10-12 --complement in.csv
```

Sin embargo, a menos que sepas lo que estás haciendo, no es recomendable manipular archivos CSV con procesadores *"genéricos"* como `sed`, `awk`, `cut`, etc. Es mejor usar herramientas que *"entiendan"* el formato CSV como está especificado en el documento técnico [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt). Por ejemplo, los dos comandos anteriores fallarían para archivos CSV válidos que contengan comas en celdas entrecomilladas.

### Propuesta recomendada

Existen [muchas](https://github.com/dbohdan/structured-text-tools#csv) herramientas diseñadas para tratar archivos CSV (RFC-4180). Las que recomiendo son:

- [xsv](https://github.com/burntsushi/xsv)

  ```bash
  xsv select '!10-12' in.csv
  ```
- [miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

  ```bash
  mlr --csv cut -x -f race_known,subject_race,person_of_color in.csv
  ```
- [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit)

  ```bash
  csvcut -C 10-12 in.csv
  ```
- [qsv](https://github.com/jqnatividad/qsv) (un fork de `xsv`)

  ```bash
  qsv select '!10-12' in.csv
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con esto
sed 's/race_known,//; s/subject_race,//; s/person_of_color,//' tu_archivo.csv > nuevo_archivo.csv

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).